# Write txt files from pandas

Tags: pandas

I've a  pandas Data Frame with two columns: 'Data' and 'ID', and I want to write one txt file for each row, the content of the file will be 'Data' and the name the 'ID'.

Comment: What type of values are in columns? `int`, `str`, `float`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [`tofile`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tofile.html):

```
print df
   ID      DATA
0   1  0.368718
1   2  0.437535
2   3  0.136219
for row in df.values:
    #print row
    row[1:].tofile(str(int(row[0]))+'.bin', sep="\t", format="%s")
```